# MySQL query breaks in PHP with use of UPPER and COUNT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query in MySQL to display results mixed case data in upper case and provide a count and it works well:

```
SELECT UPPER(City), count(*) as Counter 
FROM matrix_swfl_res 
GROUP BY City
HAVING count(*) >= 10 
ORDER BY City ASC
```

I've build a PHP page to perform this same query but zero results are returned.  I've tried to add '' to the City like this UPPER('City') and get the same zero results:

```
$query_City = "SELECT UPPER(City), count(*) as Counter 
FROM matrix_swfl_res 
GROUP BY City
HAVING count(*) >= 10 
ORDER BY City ASC";
```

Comment: BTW you also need to UPPER in group by: `GROUP BY UPPER(City)`

Comment: Also try `HAVING Counter >= 10`

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs?

Comment: @juergend Are you sure?

Comment: @Strawberry: Otherwise the group is different from what is selected.

Comment: @juergend But only if the collation is case sensitive

Comment: @Strawberry: Obviously, that must be the case. Otherwise using `upper` would be redundant.

Comment: @juergend No. Either way, in the OP's example UPPER IS redundant! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(City) AS City,
    count(*) AS Counter 
FROM matrix_swfl_res 
GROUP BY City
HAVING Counter >= 10 
ORDER BY City ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when executing  below query 
you are getting the result with Counter value below 10(most of the time 1)  :

```
SELECT UPPER(City), count(*) as Counter 
FROM matrix_swfl_res 
GROUP BY City
```

but when you applying the having condition there is no row to satisfy the condition with counter value >= 10.

Answer (score 0):

You said your query works fine when executed directly, so I'll take your word for that. Have you checked your connection in php?

Maybe you're querying the wrong database or table.